# Show Product on Product Page ASP.NET Web APP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web

Maximum (M) amount of products shown on the Product page (show only first M products, others – ignored; if M == 0, then show all products)

**How can I do this condition?**
**Do I need to do it in ProductPageModel or Product.cshtml?**

product.cshtml

```html
@page
@model GetandTake.Pages.ProductModel
@{
}
<table class="table">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ProductName</th>
            <th scope="col">QuantityPerUnit</th>
            <th scope="col">UnitPrice</th>
            <th scope="col">UnitsInStock</th>
            <th scope="col">UnitsOnOrder</th>
            <th scope="col">ReorderLevel</th>
            <th scope="col">Discontinued</th>
            <th scope="col">Category</th>
            <th scope="col">Supplier</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@product.ProductName</td>
                <td>@product.QuantityPerUnit</td>
                <td>@product.UnitPrice</td>
                <td>@product.UnitsInStock</td>
                <td>@product.UnitsOnOrder</td>
                <td>@product.ReorderLevel</td>
                <td>@product.Discontinued</td>
                <td>@product.Category</td>
                <td>@product.Supplier</td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

ProductModel product.cshtml.cs

```
public class ProductModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IProductService _productService;

    public IEnumerable<ProductsDTO> Products { get; private set; }

    public ProductModel(IProductService productService)
    {
        _productService = productService;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Products = _productService.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just need to show the M first Products, just add the `.Take()` method from `System.Linq`

```
public void OnGet()
{
    Products = _productService.GetAll().take(M);
}
```

Where `M` is your max products number.

This is only acceptable if you're NOT seeking for pagination, but just displaying N first products.
As this is a business rule, try to put it in `C#` file, not in `.cshtml`